# How to create a newtype operation in Q#?

Tags: q#

I am working with Q# on a generic grover search implementation and I wanted to define a custom Oracle type

```
    newtype ModelOracle = ((Qubit[], Qubit[], Int[], Qubit) => Unit);

    // ...

    function GroverMaxMatchingOracle(search_set: (Int,Int)[], vertices: Int[], marked_pts: Bool[]): ModelOracle {
        return ModelOracle(ApplyMaxMatchingOracle(_,_,_,_,search_set, vertices, marked_pts));
    }
```

that will fit into my model.  But when I try to use it (kind of in the same way as they use `StateOracle` in the DatabaseSearch sample), I get an error saying that the new type `ModelOracle` is not a valid operation

```
fail: Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp.Workspace[0]
  QS5021: The type of the expression must be a function or operation type. The given expression is of type OracleHelper.ModelOracle.
```

What am I getting wrong about the types here?

Comment: You'll need to share the signature of ApplyMaxMatchingOracle as well, without it it's pretty hard to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have defined things ok, so it might be that you have to unwrap the user defined type first with the `!` operator. 
So where you are using it you may have to do something like `GroverMaxMatchingOracle!(...)`

Another approach could be to name the tuple in your UDT:

```
newtype ModelOracle = (Apply: (Qubit[], Qubit[], Int[], Qubit) => Unit);
```

Then wherever you want to use it you can directly used the named item `Apply` like this: `GroverMaxMatchingOracle::Apply(...)`

If its helpful, there is a section on user defined types (8.2) in the book [@cgranade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267841/chris-granade) and I are working on, [Learn Quantum Computing with Python and Q#](https://www.manning.com/books/learn-quantum-computing-with-python-and-q-sharp?a_aid=learn-qc-granade&a_bid=ee23f338)

Comment: Thanks! this solved my issue. So from what I get from this is that UDT (operations too) are always just a tuple containing the values?

Comment: Also: you are missing a pair of parenthesis around the operation signature. the compiler complained with just that ;)